# Replacing in a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

In this program I am trying to create a coordinate plane and replace a value at a specific point. If the maximum value in the plane is 2, this code creates a 2D array with a max and minimum of 2 and numbers the axis like so:

```
String [][] grid = new String [max+max+2][max+max+2];
        for (int i=0; i<max+max+1; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<max+max+2; j++)
                grid [i][j]="o";

        for (int i=0; i<max+max+1; i++)
        {Integer Col=new Integer(max-i);
        grid [i][0]=Col.toString();}

        int [] firstRow= new int [max+max+1];
        for (int i=0; i<firstRow.length; i++)
            firstRow [i]=max-max-max+i;

ex:
   -2 -1  0  1  2
 2  o  o  o  o  o
 1  o  o  o  o  o
 0  o  o  o  o  o
-1  o  o  o  o  o
-2  o  o  o  o  o
```

In the following code an I receive random x,y coordinates for an airport (for this example say x=1 and y=-1). I have to replace the "o" in the double array with a "P" at this coordinate (1,-1). When I try to do this it is placing "P" at the correct x coordinate (1) but not at the correct y coordinate. There must be a problem with the second for loop, but I do not know what it is. The correct replacement should look like this:

```
 ex:
       -2 -1  0  1  2
     2  o  o  o  o  o
     1  o  o  o  o  o
     0  o  o  o  o  o
    -1  o  o  o  P  o
    -2  o  o  o  o  o



        Integer airx = new Integer (airport1.getX());
        Integer airy= new Integer (airport1.getY());
        for (int i=0; i<firstRow.length; i++)
            if (firstRow [i]==airport1.getX())
                airx=i;

        String yCord= airy.toString();
        for (int k=0; k<grid[0].length-1; k++)
            {String w =grid [k][0];
            if (w==yCord)

        for (int i=0; i<grid[0].length-1; i++)
            if (grid [i][0]==airy.toString())
                airy=i;
        grid [airy][airx+1]="A";
```

Comment: you should really be using brackets for most of these `for` and `if` blocks. I'd be willing to bet that's your issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array will be easier to read & index if you change from

```
   -2 -1  0  1  2
 2  o  o  o  o  o
 1  o  o  o  o  o
 0  o  o  o  o  o
-1  o  o  o  o  o
-2  o  o  o  o  o
```

to this, by changing how you generate & index the array in the first place

```
   -2 -1  0  1  2
-2  o  o  o  o  o
-1  o  o  o  o  o
 0  o  o  o  o  o
 1  o  o  o  o  o
 2  o  o  o  o  o
```

Create a variable to hold the size of the array, i.e.

```
int arrSize = 2*max + 2;
```

Create another variable to hold the array index of *position (0, 0)*.

```
int arrMid = arrSize/2;
```

You can use **grid[arrMid][arrMid]** to access *position (0, 0)*.

And in your example, **say x = 1 and y = -1**, just do this to update that position to "P":

```
Integer airx = new Integer (airport1.getX()); // 1
Integer airy= new Integer (airport1.getY());  // -1
grid[arrMid + airx][arrMid + airy] = "P";     // grid[4][2] = "P";
```